# Status of software packages for quantum compiling

Tags: programming, circuit-construction, qiskit, solovay-kitaev-algorithm, rigetti

By "quantum compiling", what I mean is classical algorithms to solve the following problem: given a $SU(D)$ matrix $U$ (the goal) and a set of $SU(D)$ unitary matrices $V_1 \cdots V_N$ (the gates), find a string $i_1\cdots i_K$ such that
$$
U \approx \prod_{k=1}^K V_{i_k}\text.
$$
In other words: given a target unitary and a set of gates, implement the target unitary from those gates. Note that I'm not just interested in optimizing a pre-existing circuit, but generating a circuit from a full unitary matrix.

What software packages are available which solve this problem? In particular, are there software packages ready-to-use with IBM Q Experience/Qiskit or Rigetti's forest?

(I understand that there are many algorithms, with different performance characteristics, which tackle this. I'm interested less in optimal performance characteristics than in low-effort usability. Is the current ecosystem well-enough-developed that I don't need to pick and implement one of these algorithms myself?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Qiskit, there are two tools you can check out.

The [two qubit kak](https://qiskit.org/documentation/_autodoc/qiskit.mapper._compiling.html#qiskit.mapper._compiling.two_qubit_kak) tool does exactly what you want for 2 qubits. If you give it a two qubit unitary, it gives you a list of gates to realize this, using the standard gate set used in Qiskit. This tool uses [Vatan and Williams optimal two-qubit circuit](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0308006). The decomposition algorithm used is explained in [Drury and Love](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.4015).

Here's an example in code

```
from qiskit.mapper import two_qubit_kak
import numpy as np

# matrix to decompose
perm = np.array([[0.,0.,0.,1.], [1.,0.,0.,0.], [0.,1.,0.,0.], [0.,0.,1.,0.] ])

#decomposition
permCircuit = two_qubit_kak(perm)
```

The corresponding result is

```
[{'name': 'u1', 'args': [0], 'params': (0.0, 0.0, 1.5707963267948968)}, {'name': 'u2', 'args': [1], 'params': (1.5707963267948966, 2.220446049250313e-16, -3.1415926535897922)}, {'name': 'cx', 'args': [1, 0], 'params': ()}, {'name': 'u1', 'args': [0], 'params': (0.0, 0.0, 1.5707963267948968)}, {'name': 'u2', 'args': [1], 'params': (1.5707963267948966, 3.141592653589793, -3.141592653589793)}, {'name': 'cx', 'args': [0, 1], 'params': ()}, {'name': 'u3', 'args': [1], 'params': (3.141592653589793, 0.0, 0.0)}, {'name': 'cx', 'args': [1, 0], 'params': ()}, {'name': 'u2', 'args': [0], 'params': (1.5707963267948966, 1.5707963267948968, -1.5707963267948957)}, {'name': 'u2', 'args': [1], 'params': (1.5707963267948966, -4.71238898038469, -1.5707963267948957)}]
```

The `u1`, etc here are single qubit rotations as defined by the [OpenQASM standard](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.03429).

Another tool is arbitary state vector initialization, which can be used for an arbitrary number of qubits. For this you can state what state vector you want, and you'll get a circuit that builds it. Obviously this is not what you asked for, but it may nevertheless be useful depending on your application.

Here's an example in code

```
qubit = QuantumRegister(2)
bit = ClassicalRegister(2)
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qubit,bit)

vector = [0, 1 / np.sqrt(3), 1 / np.sqrt(3), 1 / np.sqrt(3) ]
circuit.initialize( vector, qubit )

print(circuit)
```

Here the final print command yields

```
                       ┌───┐┌────────────┐┌───┐┌────────────┐
 q_0: |0>──────────────┤ X ├┤ Ry(0.7854) ├┤ X ├┤ Ry(2.3562) ├
         ┌────────────┐└─┬─┘└────────────┘└─┬─┘└────────────┘
 q_1: |0>┤ Ry(1.9106) ├──■──────────────────■────────────────
         └────────────┘                                      
  c_0: 0 ════════════════════════════════════════════════════

  c_1: 0 ════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Other than these existing Qiskit tools, the only algorithm I know of that is planning an implementation is that of [Iten, et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.08103). I have heard that a Mathematica version will be produced soon.